# Microsoft SSAS Average Calculation in Cube

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssas, mdx, bids

I m very new to cube development in SSAS. I m using Microsoft BIDS 2008.

I have built a small cube, which is as mentioned below:

```
    India   Pakistan GrandTotal 
Apr   6      10          16
May   5       6          11
```

I want to add a field called as average to be added beside Grand total

```
    India   Pakistan GrandTotal Average
Apr   6      10          16        8
May   5       6          11        5
```

Any inputs on this would be helpful. 5.5 in average is truncated to 5.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a calculated member that divides  current measure by the count of members in your measure group (normally a count measure is automatically created when you add a measure group).

Truncation can be handled by the FORMAT_STRING property of that calculation or by using MDX functions.

More info on calculated members:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166568(v=sql.105).aspx